# Finding the sum of 3 consecutive numbers in an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have to write a function in Python, that prints out the sum of 3 consecutive numbers in an array, for example, if the array has the following values : `[10, 20, 30, 40, 50]` it should add the first 3 numbers `(10 + 20 + 30)` and then `(20 + 30 + 40)` and then `(30 + 40 + 50)` and so on, until 50 is the last value.

my code to add all the numbers is as follows:

```
def sum_interval(values, start, stop):
    N = len(values)
    terms = np.zeros(N)

    for i in np.arange(start, stop + 1, 1):
        terms[i] = values[i]

        ans = np.sum(terms)

    return ans

arr = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50])
print(sum_interval(arr, 2, 4))
```

This following function uses the above mentioned sum_interval definition to compute the summation of the 3 consecutive numbers:

```
def sum_triplets(values):
    N = len(values)
    terms = np.zeros(N)

    for i in range(0, N, 1):
        terms[i] = sum_interval(values, i, N-1)

    return terms

arr = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50])
print(sum_triplets(arr))
```

> Expected Output: `[60, 90, 120, 90, 50]`
>
> The Output I get: `[150, 140, 120, 90, 50]`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In the `sum_triplets` function, replace the following line:

`terms[i] = sum_interval(values, i, N-1)`

with

`terms[i] = sum_interval(values, i, min(N-1,i+2))`

Comment: Thank you so much. this helped alot

Answer (score 6):

If you're already using an array, then you might as well opt for a straightforward NumPy solution. One approach would be to use [`np.convolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html) to multiply and sum an array of your desired window size of ones through your input array.

```
np.convolve(arr, np.ones(3, dtype=np.int), mode='valid')
```

**Demo**

```
>>> arr
array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50])

>>> np.convolve(arr, np.ones(3, dtype=np.int), mode='valid')
array([ 60,  90, 120])
```

---

If you're set on using a Python solution, you should avoid the intermediate array storage in your current approach - Willem has you covered with a nice answer in this case.

Answer (score 3):

I do not get why you make it that complicated: you can simply use *slicing*:

```
def sum_triplets(values):
    result = []
    for i in range(len(values)):
        result.append(sum(values[i:i+3]))
    return result
```

(boldface added for the slicing part)

You can even put this in a *one-liner* with *list comprehension*:

```
def sum_triplets(values):
    return [sum(values[i:i+3]) for i in range(len(values))]
```

Comment: I've taken to using the boldface in your answers from time to time, so thanks! Very nice for highlighting things.

Comment: Thank You so much, it really helped me a lot :) @Willem

Answer (score -1):

```
array = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
length = len(array)

n = 0
while n < length:
    m = n
    if m < length:
        first = array[n]
    if m+1 < length:
        second = array[m+1]
    else:
        second = 0
    if m+2 < length:
        third = array[m+2]
    else:
        third = 0
    result = first + second + third
    n = n+1
    print result
```